# How to reverse a xml nodes with their data in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Hi I am working with XML in java and my XML looks like

```
<Name>
<firstName>FName</firstName>
<lastName>LName</lastName>
</Name>
```

I want to convert this XML in to the below format.

```
<Name>
<FName>firstName</FName>
<LName>lastName</LName>
</Name>
```

I am looking for some API or method which will convert this in one shot. I mean converting Tags in to value and value into Tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xslt for this. The following xsl swaps all leaf node name and value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|b/@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*][parent::*]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|b/@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:element name="{.}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|b/@*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sampel program

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

    Source text = new StreamSource(new File("data.xml"));
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
    System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Name>
    <FName>firstName</FName>
    <LName>lastName</LName>
</Name>
```

Comment: thanks to you , it works like a charm can you please tell me how to start creating XSLT for my requirement....

Comment: I suppose the reversing was your requirement. For that you could use the above xslt. Do you have any additions? A simple googling gives you plenty of tutorials and examples. A simple tutorial i would suggested is one from w3schools. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/. You may also need to learn about xpath for node selection . Try http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp

Comment: If you are asking for the explanation of above xslt. It do a match for all elements from root using `match="/*"`. And with each element it apply different templates. One matches any nodes with child node (`match="*[*][parent::*]"`) and other matches leaf nodes (match="*[not(*)]"). For the former one it just duplicates the node nodes and for later one it creates a new node with tag name and value reversed.

Comment: `<Books><Book><Collection><BookName></BookName><BookAuthor></BookAuthor></Collection></Book>
</Books>`
Yes this is my requirement and I want to customize What is the XSLT for the above XML

Comment: That doesn't have any value. How do you want to reverse it?

Comment: `<Books><Book bookid='b001'><Collection id='collec001'><BookName>Java</BookName>
<BookAuthor>JavaPublisher</BookAuthor>
</Collection></Book></Books>
I want like this : 
<Books><Book bookid='b001'><Collection id='collec001'>
<Java>BookName</Java><JavaPublisher>BookAuthor</JavaPublisher>
</Collection></Book></Books>`

Comment: The above program does make this change. however it wasn't copying the attributes. I've modified the xslt to copy attributes as well. Now it should work.

Comment: thanks is their any open source tool or easy way I can do this like you

Comment: I don't know about any tool for such a requirement. There are some api to generate html form from xml or similar things.

Comment: Please tell me that can I use this same XSLT for converting vice-versa or not? Please tell me the name of API so that I can create on fly by passing XML and get corresponding XSLT

Comment: Yes you can do that with a minor modification. You see the template matching for `match="*[not(*)]"`. In that the element name is given as `name="{.}"`. this mean the current nodes value. And inside the element for value field I use `name()` method. You can interchange both to get thee reverse effect. But then it'll be same as the input. And I don't know about such an API. Most of the time xslt is written for custom requirements. :(

Comment: @SyamS <Books><Book bookid='b001'><Collection id='collec001'><BookName>Java</BookName> <BookAuthor>JavaPublisher</BookAuthor> </Collection></Book></Books> 
I want like this : 
<Books><Book bookid='b001'><Collection id='collec001'> <Java>BookName</Java><JavaPublisher>BookAuthor</JavaPublisher> </Collection></Book></Books> . Here how to persist the attributes values of bookid='b001' while using your same xslt to reverse the xml nodes with their data ?

Comment: @Utsav The code does that. It copies attributes as well.